# Parameters for modelica booleanExpression?

Tags: system-modeler

In SystemModeler, left-hand side, Libraries > Modelica > Blocks > Examples > ShowLogicalSources, we see a diagram with several disconnected blocks:

[image]

The `booleanExpression` block contains an expression, `pulse.y and step.y`, that implicitly links it to the other blocks -- by "implicitly," I mean "without connectors drawn on the canvas surface."  The [documentation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nkg6.png) states "The (time varying) Boolean output signal of this block can be defined in its parameter menu via variable y," so I go look at (what I think is) the parameter menu for that block, but there are no parameters:

[image]

Notice that the block is properly selected in the UI (green outline). Also, I checked that the other blocks have parameters. Here are the parameters for block `step`, for instance:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Without the ability to inspect and edit the `booleanExpression` in the block, it's pretty much useless.

EDIT: I should add that I clicked every menu item, every promising-looking icon in the "component browser" on the right-hand side of the screen, and right-clicked every context-menu item looking for some way to open up the instance and change its parameters. I didn't find any way.

Comment: A version of this question was answered on Wolfram Community: [link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/336238?p_p_auth=N3Lpe5FR)